# Did I accidentally ruin this circuit board?

Tags: batteries, pcb, circuit-design, wire

I was advised to remove the old solder so I read online that I can do it with a knife. I scraped it off, but now I'm not sure if it's ruined or if it still works.

Here is the original (B+ and underneath B-):

[image]

And here is after I removed the old solder:

[image]

I want to make sure I am still OK to go to add new solder over it.

Comment: Can you test the connections using a multimeter?

Comment: I don't have that tool... I was hoping someone could have just checked based on the images but maybe I should buy one to be safe.

Comment: Can't say for sure if you killed the entire PCB but you did ruin the tracks around the LED holes. As Simon mentioned, please never use knife or a sharp tool to remove solder.

Comment: No, you can not use a knife.  Maybe you misread the article and it said to liquify the solder with hot air or a soldering gun first???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a very close look at the surrounding tracks and make sure you haven't accidentally cut them.

But the simplest way to see is to try soldering new wires on.

And don't attack circuit boards with knives in the future.  There are better ways to remove old solder (desoldering braid, or a solder sucker).  And most of the time, there's no real need to remove the solder anyway.

Comment: regarding soldering new wires, since I've never done this, do I cover the metals inside the wire with black tape and then just solder it on top of the black tape?

Comment: @Awsmike No black tape.  A soldering iron, and some solder should be all you need.  Old-fashioned lead solder is easier than the modern lead-free stuff, if you can find it.  Soldering on small contacts like that should be fast.  If you need to hold the soldering iron on for more than about a second, you're doing it wrong.  If you overheat the board and cause the tracks to peel off, it will be ruined beyond repair.

Comment: No you don't solder on black tape. You solder the wires to the pads. Which hopefull are working. And you need to reapply more solder as you carved the old solder off. Don't do that and you were already been told to get help from someone with a soldering iron.

Comment: Thanks Simon! That's been helpful. @Justme - I understand I was told to get help from someone but I'm trying to learn. I just ordered a soldering iron. Thank you all for the info.

Comment: @Awsmike soldering takes practice to get right.  On small electronics, it needs speed, accuracy and delicacy.  I have seen too many questions here from people asking how to repair a board when the pads have peeled off.

Comment: Understood! Thanks Simon!

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to determine if the Printed Circuit Board (PCB) has been damaged only using pictures.  One would have to check continuity for all the scratched traces.  Removing the solder resist, which is green in this case, should not affect continuity.  However this does expose the trace as a wire which has been stripped of its insulation.

Avoid physically removing solder from a PCB.  The traces, usually copper, are attached to the underlying board, usually fiber glass, and will break off with excessive physical manipulation or excessive heat.

Instead, use a product commonly known as [solder wick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desoldering#Desoldering_braid) (aka Desoldering braid, desoldering wick).  Place the solder wick (braided wire) over the solder to be removed and heat it from above with a solder iron. Remove the solder wick after the solder is wicked up but before the solder solidifies.

Alternatively, a [desoldering tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desoldering#Desoldering_pump) (aka solder sucker) can be used. But may require some practice.

Comment: I've found a solder sucker works a lot better most of the time than solder wick.

Comment: I hear you.  My experience (what I do) is go w/the wick for SMD work and solder sucker for through hole parts.  But there are always exceptions.  This is where experience and practice  come into play.